# Associating copied page with original

Tags: wagtail

After reading the Wagtail documentation I came to the conclusion that there is no easy way to determine if a page was copied, and if so, from which page.  Am I correct, or is there a way to determine if a page is actually a copy, and not an original.

I know that Wagtail 1.9 will have the 'before_copy_page' and 'after_copy_page' hooks.  I will use this for future pages, but I still need something for all the current pages in my database.

Comment: How do you "copy" the page?  Is this something the site user does?  Or an editor?  If site developers do this, you could have them subclass the original Page, rather than subclassing Page directly.

Comment: The copying is done by the editors of the site(s).  We currently do subclass the Page class, so one way to do this is to manually extend the 'copy' method that Wagtail calls when a page is copied.  I was just wondering if there is a simpler way to do this, i.e., if Wagtail already has a feature for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no way to determine whether a page was copied based on what's in the database. However the copy function calls `page.copy()` ([source code](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/ed01d58b57263a3f4d85cfa6e3ded676a68ddeb1/wagtail/wagtailcore/models.py#L1074-L1211)), and there the event is logged:

```python
# Log
logger.info("Page copied: \"%s\" id=%d from=%d", page_copy.title, page_copy.id, self.id)
```

If you keep your logs, you could parse them for entries looking like:

```
Page copied: "Test page" id=55 from=12
```